# Idiomatic way to use __container__.lookupFactory in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

In the notes of [this commit](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/5becdc4467573f80a5c5dbb51d97c6b9239714a8), the Ember team have made it very clear that `App.__container__.lookup()` is not the way to get at controllers. Instead we should use the `needs` property.

I understand the rationale behind this, and the idiomatic way to access singleton controllers.

However, in my app, I have some cases where I need instance controllers. In that case, I am using `App.__container__.lookupFactory()` to get at the prototype which I can then `create()` or `extend()`

Is there a better way to do this (without using `__container__`?

Edit:

Here is an example use case.

```
App.MyContainerView = Ember.ContainerView.extend

  ...

  addChildView: ->
    @get("content").pushObject(App.MyChildView.create(...))
```

The above example will push a new view onto the stack (allowing views to be dynamically created)

However, these views will (may?) not have the right container (and other properties?) set due to being created using `App.MyChildView.create()`. This is especially true in cases where we are doing a partial integration of Ember into an existing app.

The way to create these views would instead be:

```
App.__container__.lookupFactory("view:my_child").create()
```

In which case everything would be ok.

Additional use cases exist, for creating instance controllers outside the context of the router.. but the idea is the same.

Comment: Can you provide code to understand your use case

Comment: If you are using the lookup factory to get the Class, why don't you just use the class name in the first place?  App.FooController is just as good as App.__container__.lookupFactory('controller:foo') and seems far more idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you're still looking for an answer. I am also struggling with how to do things "the Ember way".

This answer put me on the right track, and should be relevant to your question:
["Please ensure this controller was instantiated with a container"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24169955/please-ensure-this-controller-was-instantiated-with-a-container)

As for me, I had the same problem as in the above question: when I manually instantiated my `App.AnyOtherController` with `App.AnyOtherController.create(...)`, then inside this controller, I could not access dependency injections (such as a session object that I make available to all my controllers and routes).

Instantiating the same controller this way solves the problem by giving the controller a container:
`this.container.lookupFactory('controller:any_other').create(...)`

You should be able to access `this.container` from any view, and I guess, any controller, as long as they have been given a container.

You can `Ember.String.decamelize('AnyOther')` to convert the CamelCase controller name to a suitable string.

More on containers here: http://ember.zone/beginning-to-understand-the-ember-js-container/

If it doesn't help *you*, I still hope this helps someone out there, as this container stuff is a bit tricky at first...

Comment: OMG `this.container` of course! Man I can't believe I didn't even think of that.

Comment: why did you need to do App.AnyOtherController.create(...)? you should not be manually creating any controller

Comment: I remember having had to create a controller manually for a good reason (or what seemed like one!). Keep in mind that this answer was based on code I had written for Ember 1.x, where views hadn't been superseded by components yet, and many other things were different.